# How to reuse plist from IOS Apps into our android apps

Tags: android, plist

I want to use plist file data in android for that tell any best way to read plist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it.

```
String pList = StorageUtils.getFilePathFromAssetsOrLocalStorage(this, "some.plist");
PListXMLHandler handler = new PListXMLHandler();
        PListXMLParser parser = new PListXMLParser();
        parser.setHandler(handler);
        parser.parse(pList);
        PList list = ((PListXMLHandler) parser.getHandler()).getPlist();
        Array arr = (Array) list.getRootElement();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Dict dict = (Dict) arr.get(i);
            DictItem item = DictItem.parse(this, dict, "");}
```

Comment: here how to get particular item @alican akyol

Comment: how to add PListXMLHandler, Plist, Dict class

Comment: PListXmlHandler class's package name is com.longevitysoft.android.xml.plist;